# Is there a way to disable HDMI Video output?

Tags: display, audio, hdmi

I have a 2020 Mac Mini (M1) along with a CalDigit TS3+ Dock. I had been using Optical Audio via the CalDigit dock, but I wanted surround sound support and realized the Optical did not have it. I have an AV Processor with a full surround set up hooked up, however I am actually using an old DVI-Dual Link display (Using an active DVI-D to DisplayPort adapter, plugged into the dock). The audio I just hooked up with HDMI to one of the inputs on the processor.

My problem is, when I switch inputs on my processor, every time I switch back to the Mac it now thinks it's a second display and invariably treats my existing monitor as the second screen and shifts all the open windows to the imaginary second display that I cannot see. I am not using the HDMI out of the processor and do not wish to use it, only to use HDMI for surround audio.

Is there some way I can either disable the HDMI as a display device or make it so every time I switch inputs it does not do this? Command + F1 does not seem to do anything (I even installed Karabiner Elements and ensured my non-Apple keyboard had the function keys mapped as F1-F12 and confirmed in Keyboard Viewer). I have to manually open System Preferences, go to Displays -> Arrangement, and then click mirror screens. It of course always defaults to the processor which for some reason it has a lower resolution, so I have to also select my monitor in "Optimize For".

This is really tedious every time I switch the input, but I don't know if Mac OS supports some way to disable the video output from HDMI so it still passes audio without trying to treat it like a second display. Seems like most others asking want to disable the audio from HDMI, but I want to disable video only and leave the audio.

Comment: The optical should have 5.1 support, but the Mac will see it as stereo. It can carry AC3 audio to an external decoder, but will not decode it itself (licensing issues).

Comment: @Tetsujin What is something that offers that I can use to verify? I had found [this](https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/multichannel.html) which worked when using HDMI, but only works in stereo via optical. Netflix does not support 5.1 on Mac Os that I can tell, so I'm sort of at a loss of anything that I can use to verify it works.

Comment: something like this - https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/multichannel.html I've no idea about Netflix, I don't use it, sorry. Oops, same link

Comment: That works fine for me over optical, played from VLC.